# Cannot see object when moving

Tags: inkscape, tools

I cannot see the object moving or resizing in real time. Like in this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aqWEJoGHpPo

I see the object move along with the cursor when she is moving the object. In my inkscape, all I see is a blue box when resizing and moving (the object moves but I cannot see it in real time like the video above:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shapes not showing in Inkscape](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/39496/shapes-not-showing-in-inkscape)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click *Edit > Preferences* . Then under *Tools*, click on *Selector*, and make sure the option *When transforming show Objects* is selected. If it's set to *box outline*, only the box will be visible when moving.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I never went in the settings and was clueless as to how a setting changed automatically.