# When I draw a simple rectangle, it doesn’t appear

Tags: inkscape

When I try to draw a rectangle, it does not appear. I can fill it but I don’t want to. I just want a normal rectangle with borders. How to do it?

Comment: Related: [Shapes not showing in Inkscape](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/39496/19174)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a stroke to the rectangle.

To do it, open the Fill & Stroke panel <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, choose the Stroke Paint tab to choose a colour, and then in the Stroke Style tab, choose a suitable width of stroke. Note: if the width of stroke is set to 0, it won't be visible.

Example

[image]

It's also possible to set the stroke colour and width by right clicking on the stroke colour box, or width shown at the bottom of the main window.

[image]

You can also <kbd>Shift</kbd>+Click a colour on the colour palette to set the stroke colour.

Comment: Thank you, i´ve figured it also out in the meantime :-)